# boost::spirit X3 -- Why can it not be found from the list of libraries?

Tags: boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

Why is this library not listed in the directory of the matching boost version?
What are the differences compared to v2.*?
What are the required/supported C++ standards?

Answer (score 0):

X3 is not a boost library. It's a component of the Boost Spirit library.

The documentation is here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/index.html

It requires c++14, but there are deprecation warning that in the future they will only support c++17. In fact I just found (on that page) they already do:

> WARNING*: C++14 compilers support will be dropped soon.
> Spirit X3 in Boost 1.81 (scheduled to November 2022) will use C++17 features.

The differences are legion, but you can find them by reading the docs.

I guess besides that, you can find some of that info on this site:

1. Maturity

   ```
   - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48237777/is-boost-spirit-x3-production-ready/48239766#48239766
   - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45014216/how-future-safe-is-it-to-write-a-parser-with-boost-spirit-x3/45015809#45015809
   - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52990661/getting-into-boost-spirit-qi-or-x3/52991170#52991170
   ```
2. Differences

   - [Statefulness of Spirit V2 and X3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45457868/statefulness-of-spirit-v2-and-x3/45469919)
   - [What are contexts in boost spirit X3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66393775/what-are-contexts-in-boost-spirit-x3/66394164#66394164)
3. Overcoming differences/missing bits:

   - [Spirit X3: parser with internal state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50821925/spirit-x3-parser-with-internal-state/50824603#50824603)
   - [Boost Spirit X3 cannot compile repeat directive with variable factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33624149/boost-spirit-x3-cannot-compile-repeat-directive-with-variable-factor/33627991#33627991)
   - [Boost spirit x3 - lazy parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60171119/boost-spirit-x3-lazy-parser/60176802#60176802)
4. Advanced Use

   - [Spirit X3, Is this error handling approach useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57048008/spirit-x3-is-this-error-handling-approach-useful/57067207#57067207)
   - [Is it possible to use "boost::spirit::qi::as_string" in a loop? If so, can someone help me find the solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76074989/is-it-possible-to-use-boostspiritqias-string-in-a-loop-if-so-can-someo/76076246#76076246)
5. Common Pitfalls

   - [Spirit X3, How to get attribute type to match rule type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56819120/spirit-x3-how-to-get-attribute-type-to-match-rule-type/56824271#56824271)
   - [boost::spirit::x3 attribute compatibility rules, intuition or code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37201023/boostspiritx3-attribute-compatibility-rules-intuition-or-code/37204957#37204957)
   - [Boost.Spirit X3 compile time explodes with recursive rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46950769/boost-spirit-x3-compile-time-explodes-with-recursive-rule/46955184#46955184)
   - Unresolved symbols due to varying contexts https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+x3+unresolved

I could go on, but it's probably better to search/ask targeted questions if you run into more.

#### TL/DR

As I happen to have recommended someone else yesteday:

> @sehe. Since I'm using the latest boost version (1.82,0), do you recommend using QI or X3 for this project? They both new for me to learn anyway. I just don't want to spend time upgrading this to X3 in the future. –
> [Dylan
> 6 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76416623/whats-wrong-with-my-c-boost-spirit-grammar-rules/76418652?noredirect=1#comment134774544_76418652)

> I think Qi is more mature and has fewer surprises (especially surrounding automatic propagation). However, X3 is a lot quicker to compile. If you are prepared to do a lot manual massaging with semantic actions anyways, X3 might be easier, since they're bit more natural now. –
> [sehe
> 5 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76416623/whats-wrong-with-my-c-boost-spirit-grammar-rules/76418652?noredirect=1#comment134775326_76418652)